# How do I change the header color of a specific part of the code on a preset Shopify theme?

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes, shopify

How do I change the header color of a specific part of the code on a preset Shopify theme?

```
class="site-header__upper page-width"
```

---

```
{% section 'header' %}

  <div class="page-container page-element is-moved-by-drawer">
    <main class="main-content" id="MainContent" role="main">
      {{ content_for_layout }}
    </main>


  {% section 'footer' %}   </div>'''
```

---

[Picture of screenshot of developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htufO.jpg)

[Screenshot of code in shopify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coAxC.png)

Comment: Check out the following tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: FYI, as you experiment further, it might be handy to know that SO has a sister site dedicated to WordPress questions at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the style's file and then :

```css
.site-header__upper.page-width {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: I can't find it, uploaded a screenshot of what I see in the style's file

Comment: Here's the color variable. If you want, you can change it and pick another from [here](https://www.color-hex.com/color-palettes/).


Another way to do it is to apply a new css rule with the code provided code on the top.